# Using Bindings to trigger a style change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers, styles

Hopefully someone can help here.

I have a ListView that is populated by a List Property in my ViewModel.

I have another List Property in my ViewModel that contains the Rows in the UI I need highlighting.

```
   <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

This does exactly what is looks like, any item I select in the ListView highlights in Red.
I want to be able to Bind this style trigger to the List property in my ViewModel.

Anybody know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a property called `IsSelected` on your item and bind it to your `ListViewItem.IsSelected`

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Edit**

If you want to apply other style setters based on a property in your DataItem, use a DataTrigger instead of a regular Trigger. Regular Triggers are only meant to be used on UI Element properties, not bindings.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Please read the question fully.  I said "I have another List Property in my ViewModel that contains the Rows in the UI I need highlighting." "I want to be able to Bind this style trigger to the List property in my ViewModel."

Comment: @SheikYerbouti I'm afraid I don't understand your question then. Your ViewModel should not have UI objects, it should have data objects. The ideal way of doing this would be to have your data objects reflect your view, so if you want to track selected items in your ViewModel, then the data objects should have something like an `IsSelected` property. If you really want to have two lists of items, then loop through the selected items list, find the item in the data list, and set it's `IsSelected` property to true

Comment: The ViewModel has no UI logic, the UI has no code. As per MVVM.  I have two list properties in my MVVM one containing all the objects I want in my list, and one containing the objects I want highlighted.  The isSelected is just an example.  I want to apply that trigger to a bunch of items in the list view. I want those items to be determined by the list of objects in my MVVM.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti Your only other option would be to use a `MultiConverter` which accepts parameters for the data item, and the list of selected items, and looks to see if the data item exists in the list of items. I would not recommend that.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti The `ViewMode`l is meant to reflect the view. If there is a `CheckBox` that needs checking, the `ViewModel` should store the `IsChecked` value somewhere. Same thing goes for Selected Items. If you need to store selected items in the `ViewModel`, you need a property to store `IsSelected` in. ViewModels should not reference the view, but they should reflect the view's data.

Comment: What you recommend doing?  I can't see any alternative, it does not appear to be very easy to apply the same style to multiple items in a ListView.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti I recommend adding an `IsSelected` boolean property to the data item that the `ListView` is bound to. So if your `ListView` is bound to `ObservableCollection<MyDataItem>`, then `MyDataItem` should have a boolean value which determines if the item is selected or not. I would call it `IsSelected` because that is what the value would represent, however it could be called anything you want.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.  I was hoping I would not have to change my model to do this but I guess that is better than pissing about with WPF styles. Cheers.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti If you wish to set a style setter based on some condition in your data object, you would use a `DataTrigger`. See the update to my answer for an example.

Comment: @SheikYerbouti I would also suggest adding a property like `IsSelected` to your view model. I think it would probably benefit you also to change your data structure. However, you could make that new view model property dynamic. So in the `get` you can look through your list and in the `set` you can add something to your list.